# How do I make a list of data frames generated by loops in R?

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe, for-loop

How do I make a list of data frames generated by loops?

This is my loop:

```
> for (i in 1:3) {
+     x <- c(1:3)
+     y <- c(1:3)
+     df1 <- data.frame("col1"=i*3, "col2"=y+i*3)
+     print(df1)
+ }
  col1 col2
1    3    4
2    3    5
3    3    6
  col1 col2
1    6    7
2    6    8
3    6    9
  col1 col2
1    9   10
2    9   11
3    9   12
```

> But when I run df1 this happens:

```
> print(df1)
  col1 col2
1    9   10
2    9   11
3    9   12
```

> This is what I'd like to see:

```
print(df1)
  col1 col2
1    3    4
2    3    5
3    3    6
  col1 col2
1    6    7
2    6    8
3    6    9
  col1 col2
1    9   10
2    9   11
3    9   12
```

Any help is immensely appreciated! thanks

Comment: The issue is that you overwrite `df1` in each iteration.

Comment: yes! I understand that now, I'm just trying to apply your idea into this specific scenario that I'm dealing here. I saw a similar answer but I couldn't replicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
x <- c(1:3)                       # no need for y because its the same as x
out <- vector("list", length(x))  # pre-allocate space for the three data.frames 
for (i in x) {
  # fill the list with the data.frames
  out[[i]] <- data.frame("col1" = i*3, "col2" = x + i*3)
}
```

Result

```
out
#[[1]]
#  col1 col2
#1    3    4
#2    3    5
#3    3    6

#[[2]]
#  col1 col2
#1    6    7
#2    6    8
#3    6    9

#[[3]]
#  col1 col2
#1    9   10
#2    9   11
#3    9   12
```

Comment: I got it! really appreciate!